# How Is A Provisioning Profile Linked To Certificate?

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, provisioning-profile

I have recently upgraded to the beta version of XCode and in the Code Signing section of a project I created for iOS 7.1 there is a dropdown to select the Code Signing Identity and this seems to be linked back to the Certificate created on the developers portal.  This now displays a long GUID type string instead of the ad hoc distribution certificate that was available in XCode 5.1.1.

In the Provisioning Profile dropdown it now defaults to "Automatic" and does not find the original provisioning profile that I had associate with this project in XCode 5.1.1.

I have tried refreshing the account used for this certificate and it seems to try to update the code signing identity but doesn't retrieve the latest.

All of my certificates and provisioning profiles are up-to-date (not expired) and they are installed on the device I have connected.

What has changed in XCode that breaks compiling for iOS based on valid certificates?